# CSS making div appear to grow up when hovering over a character next to it

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to make the blue square appear to grow up (by increasing the padding on top) when hovering over the character on the left, i tried increasing the padding-top but it shifts the position of the square down making it seem like it is growing down instead of growing up, i have tried various things but i can't seem to make it grow up.

```css
:root {--font-size: 16px;}
* {list-style-type: none;}
html {font-size: var(--font-size);}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    min-height: 10em;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    margin-inline: 1em;
    height: 10em;
}

.h {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.5em;
    left: 1em;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em; 
}

h2:hover + .h {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2>A</h2>
          <div class="h"></div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Currently your blue squares gets bigger when hovering over the letter. Please edit question and include the desired behaviour

Comment: Like what @Huangism said, what do you mean by "grow up"?

Comment: What is the purpose of the blue div. I'm pretty sure you could handle this a better way.

Comment: I have edited the post to hopefully better explain my question.
I mean when hovering the letter the blue square gets bigger but in the wrong direction i was hoping to make it get bigger in the opposite direction it does right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the square grow or move in an upward direction, you can use a negative `margin-top` with the same value as your positive `padding-top`:

```
padding-top: 1em;
margin-top: -1em;
```

```css
:root {--font-size: 16px;}
* {list-style-type: none;}
html {font-size: var(--font-size);}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    min-height: 10em;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    margin-inline: 1em;
    height: 10em;
}

.h {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.5em;
    left: 1em;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em; 
}

h2:hover + .h {
    padding-top: 1em;
    margin-top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2>A</h2>
          <div class="h"></div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, i am still learning and don't quite understand why it behaves that way but it works.

Comment: @Rafaeleh it works because your square is getting bigger by 1em and negative margin top pulls the square up by 1em so the bottom looks like it is not moving. Regular margin top pushes element down where negative margin top pulls them up

Comment: @Huangism Thanks i do understand that, i meant why adding padding top makes the position of the square go down, is it because of the align-center inside the li? but shouldn't the position absolute overwrite that and keep it at the same position relative to the parent? or perhaps i am confusing something here.

Comment: @Rafaeleh it is because your square is positioned absolutely from the top `top: 4.5em;` so your square will always start at position, adding padding top simply pushes the content inside of the square down. So if you updated the top value to 3.5em on hover then it would have worked as well `top: 3.5em;` instead of the negative margin

Comment: @Huangism hmm i see now, i thought the position was in relation to the bottom of the square, as i added padding to the top, but it positions it so it has 4.5em of space between the start of the box and the top. Thank you for the clarification it makes a lot of sense now, i was indeed confusing things.

Comment: @Rafaeleh if you want the box to sit xx from the bottom then don't use top and use bottom instead `bottom: 1em` for example. Once an element is positioned absolutely, it will start from the top/bottom/left/right that you define